# Cassandra - data modelling help needed

Tags: cassandra

I try to design social network ( kind of ) application.
I have a User, he has Follower(s), and there is a Timeline.
My timeline table look like:

```
user_id
second_party_user_id
created
other_fields
```

So, when 'second_party_user' posts any new content, I get all people who follow him, and insert into their Timeline second_party_user's post.
When user comes to see timeline, I do a simple request to his timeline by user_id.
The problem is that I need to get ordered items. And if I want to get ordered by created, I need to put it as a second clustering column, not a third one.
At the same time, if I put it as a second clustering column, ie:

```
user_id
created
second_party_user_id
other_fields
```

then I would have a problem when one user unfollows second_party_user, ie how can I delete by (user_id, second_party_user_id).

Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle those features you can use two tables, one for get the timeline ordered and another one to handle the elimination in both tables.

```
//order timeline by created date
user_id(pk) 
created(ck)
second_party_user_id 
other_fields

//with this table you can get created to delete in the first one and 
//delete this table with (user_id,second_party_user_id)
user_id(ck) 
second_party_user_id (ck)
created
other_fields
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although, I am not completely sure I follow you.
How do I get all timeline items of a user knowing only his user_id?
( ok, possibly with secondary index or sasi index ).
But how do I delete all items of a second_user from user's timeline?
I know only two things: user_id and second_party_user_id. 
Secondary index or sasi index do not support deletion..

Comment: I understand wrong the question, i edited my answer to adapt it to your features

Comment: OK, thanks. Not the best one, but definitely possible one.